# Is there anyway to get the console window to stay open once program is done and close after 1 keystroke?

Tags: c++, command-line

A command line program always closes the window after it has finished executing. I know you can use `cin.get();` to wait for the user to enter input. Is there a way where the user could press any key (instead of entering something then pressing enter) to close the program? I don't want to use `system("PAUSE")` as it's Windows specific and slow.

I want it to pause so that the user can see it completed successfully and other details. It would probably not be run from an already open command line and the executable would be double clicked to run.

Comment: A command line program doesn't have a window to close. It should simply output to the same window as the one the command line was entered in.

Comment: in C you can do `getchar()` and then exit

Comment: I would just make the thing that *ran* this program handle that, as it is unlikely this behavior is wanted if run from a console/shell: a shell/script wrapper, perhaps?

Comment: Why is there a close vote, no one has provided a solution? This is a question, the user wants to know the results of the program (after double clicking the executable in the GUI). I didn't think it would be that hard, lol.

Comment: I would use `cin.get();` and just press the enter key (one keystroke).

Comment: @Celeritas There seems to be a lot of confusion/debate as to "how" this program is being invoked and if invoking it as such is an "incorrect invocation". David and I agree (although we disagree too ;-) that the C program *is correct* without this pause (and adding such a pause to the program is not desirable), and whatever calls the program (be it opening a console window and executing the command that way, or otherwise) is what needs to be corrected.

Comment: @pst: Invoking a program in a window that is temporary when you want the window to be permanent is an incorrect invocation. There's no way to fix it in a portable program because a portable program has no way to even tell if it's in a window. (Pausing in all cases breaks use of the program for things like pipes or redirecting to a file. That's a very bad choice.)

Comment: WHy are you complaining that without `PAUSE`, your program is instant, and with `PAUSE` it's too "slow".  That's just confusing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I do not disagree at all.

Comment: @pst the program may be used my non-technical people. Most likely it will be used on Windows. Most likely the user will double click the file. I have a few things I want the user to know once the program is finished.

Comment: @Celeritas Would it be possible to distribute an appropriate "run.bat" or "run.sh" script with the program? Then said wrappers could contain `PAUSE` or that which is desirable/appropriate for the given operating system ..

Comment: @Celeritas: There is no good portable solution. There are bad solutions and there are non-portable solutions. But there's no elegant way to fix incorrect invocation. You could pause for a keypress only on Windows. That's perhaps the least awful solution.

Comment: @Celeritas - There seems to be much, frankly, irrelevant debate.  TWO SUGGESTIONS: 1) if you want your program to "pause", a good, portable way to do it is "std::cin.get()".  That's what I tried to suggest in the first place.  2) If you want *Windows* to pause your program, you can invoke it with "start /wait".  'Hope that helps

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so there's no proper solution? I'm surprised because I guessed this scenario would be popular.

Comment: it is command line program so you can have command line argument if it will do some std::cin.get() or getchar() at end or no. If it was windows question then there is also some property of console window if to close it or not when the program terminates.

Comment: @paulsm4 with `std::cin.get()` you need to press a key then press enter, I would prefer just pressing any key.

Comment: @Celeritas: The proper solution is either to educate users about how to run command line programs or to supply a GUI program instead of a command line program on Windows. Unfortunately, those aren't very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  "system("PAUSE") is one way.  A simple "getchar()" or "cin" should be absolutely equivalent :)

Comment: No, `system("PAUSE")` is **not** one way. This is a C++ question. You have no idea what "PAUSE" might do on an arbitrary C++ machine.

Comment: @David Schwartz - look dude, your rude comment about "doesn't have a window to close" was completely off-base.  We both know the OP meant "a windows command prompt appeared, and I want to keep it up until the user dismisses it."  "`System("PAUSE")`" is one way (albeit a poor way) to accomplish this on Windows.  "std::cin.get()" is preferable.  That's all I suggested.

Comment: As David said, **do not** use `system("PAUSE");` use `getchar` or `cin`

Comment: The OP isn't on Windows though. The OP specifically said he didn't want to use `system("PAUSE")` because it's Windows-specific. If the OP was only on Windows, why would that matter?

Answer (score -1):

It's an option with the OS and not in C/C++. It needs to control how the Terminal open and close.
Just like if you called a batch or a command line app.

It's too platform dependent to post a code or config here (basically a Console GUI application with onClose statement in our IDE)